# slither : The term 'slither' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat, python, slither

Ive been trying to install slither for the last two days but i keep getting this weird error and im not exactly sure why, does anyone know what it means? my operating system is windows[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue. I have uninstalled the python v0.3.11 and I have installed python v0.3.9, which works for me.